# ASP.net MVC Q:An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.Help me

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

First I created a model class by name Album then built the solution and then created controller using entity framework now I dont know it works okay when i compile it with this http://localhost:61915/ but when I give it  http://localhost:61915/Albums it generates the error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: If you want answers ASAP, add a bit more info. have you debugged? what line of code is giving you the error? Was there an inner exception?

Comment: can you post your albums controller's code block

Comment: public class AlbumsController : Controller
    {
        private MVCMusicContext db = new MVCMusicContext();

        // GET: Albums
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Albums.ToList()); //This giving me error
        }

        // GET: Albums/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger yes I have debugged it

Comment: You need to verify that your Albums model is setup correctly. Do you have a database with a table named "Albums". Are the fields in your model named the same as your db table? Is your web.config pointing to the correct database? The inner exception should tell you more. If that's not it, please post your model code. Also it helps us if you edit your question to add your code blocks instead of in a comment, it's hard to read code in a comment.